# Which file is consuming most of the bandwidth?

Tags: cpanel, bandwidth, whm, memory-bandwidth

My website is consuming much more bandwidth than it supposed to be. From Weblizer or awstats of WHM/ cPanel I can monitor the bandwidth usage, which type of files (jpg, png, php, css etc.) is consuming the bandwidth. But I couldn't get any specific file name. My assumption is the bandwidth usage is done by referral spaming. But from the "Visitors" page of cPanel I can see only last 1000 hits. Is there any way from where I can see that which image or css file is consuming the bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a particular file which you think is consuming the most bandwidth, then you use apachetop tool.
yum install apachetop

then run

apachetop -f /var/log/apache2/domlogs/website_name-ssl.log

replace website_name with which you wish too.

It will basically pick the entries from domlogs (which saves requests being served from websites, you may read more about [domlogs here](https://www.basezap.com/learn-about-domlogs/)).

This will show the file which is being requested the most in real time basis and might give you an idea if particular image/php etc file has maximum requests.

Domlogs is a way to find which file request by which bot etc is being carried out. Your initial investigation may start from this point.